# Neo4j RESTAPI Batch cypher JSON parse issue

Tags: neo4j

I'm posting the following to /db/data/batch in the attempt to retrieve a node and update its properties in one go.

`[{"method":"POST","to":"/cypher","body":{"params":{},"query":"start x = node(683) return x"},"id":1},{"method":"PUT","to":"{1}/properties","body":{"score":100,"pp":1},"id":2}]`

From what I've seen [online](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html) it looks OK, But I'm getting the following error response

```
onData:  {

  "message" : "Illegal character in path at index 2: ./{1}/properties",

 "exception" : "IllegalArgumentException",

  "fullname" : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
```

If it matters I'm Using AS3-JSON and neo4j 2.0 I suspect its something to with Flash's JSON.stringify messing up the "{1}/properties" yet the outgoing message looks fine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't batch cypher and refer to the things returned by it, AFAIK.

If you're doing cypher, you could just do `start x=node(683) set x.score=100, x.pp=1`. (passing in params)